# ClassNotFoundException during Dynamic Class loading in android

Tags: android, class, exception, dynamic

I am creating an app, where i am supposed to receive data through web service.

Here i am having a class, stored in the main package. I need to load data of this class dynamically i.e at run time, whenever something is received from the web service. But i am getting excepion of classNotFound.

Here is my code for dynamic loading of class,

```
try
{
    Class myClass = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("com.myPackage.it.ClassToLoad");
    Log.d("Dynamic class Loading", "1");
    Object DPMInstance = myClass.newInstance();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
          "Get Methods" + myClass.getMethods(), 5000).show();
    Method myMethod = myClass.getMethod("sayHello", new Class[] {});      
    myMethod.invoke(DPMInstance, new Object[] { }); 
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.d("Error", "" + e);
}
```

I am getting excpetion at this line,

```
Class myClass = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("com.myPackage.it.ClassToLoad");
```

Comment: Are you sure that the class file you are trying to load exists at the specified path?

Comment: Alternatively you may have a look at the very first answer in this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565804/classnotfoundexception-for-class-file-on-classpath

Comment: yes, the class exists at same location.

Comment: Is it declared in your manifest?

Comment: Its a simple class, not an activity. So i dont think, i need to declare it in manifest.

Comment: I have been suffering same problem since yesterday.
I confuse the process about what kind of file is needed.
.class file / .jar file / dexed jar file?