# Dynamic class loading in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to inject features to my android app.
However I have been suffering 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'.
What kind of things am I missing?

1. Simple class (just a .class file )
2. Layout and resources
3. Activities

First of all I want to do 1.
But there are so many ways to implement, I confuse how to realize this.

**Assumption:**

1.File is downloaded into local data repository.

2.targetClassName is com.example.mari.myandroid.TestDinamicLoad.

3.SDK & Build Tools version, (with no proguard)
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

**Pattern A: Using URLClassLoader**

Compile: gradle compilation and this is just raw class file

URL: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Hrot21k8nYZ2pWNXBBMU5Qd2M/view?usp=sharing

```
    private void urlLoader(final File file){
        try {
            URL myurl[] = {new URL("file:" + file.toString())};
            URLClassLoader x = new URLClassLoader(myurl);
            Class c = x.loadClass(this.targetClassName);
            for (Field f : c.getDeclaredFields()) {
                Log.v(TAG, f.getName() + " : " + f.toString());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.v(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
```

**Pattern B: Using dexLoader**

Compile:

```
    javac -classpath /Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/platforms/android-22/android.jar TestDinamicLoad.java
    dx --dex --output TestDinamicLoad.jar TestDinamicLoad.java
```

URL:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Hrot21k8nYdG9wdHhiOWJIVE0/view?usp=sharing

```
    private void dexLoader(final File file){
    try {
        Context ctx     = getApplicationContext();
        String         dex_dir = ctx.getDir("dex", 0).getAbsolutePath();
        ClassLoader    parent  = getClass().getClassLoader();
        DexClassLoader loader  = new DexClassLoader(file.getPath(), dex_dir, null, parent);
        Class          c       = loader.loadClass(this.targetClassName);
        Object         o       = c.newInstance();
        Method m       = c.getMethod("func");

        m.invoke(o);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v(TAG, e.toString());
    }

}
```

Errors:

```
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani: urlLoader------
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.mari.myandroid.TestDinamicLoad
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:753)
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at com.example.mari.myandorid2.MainActivity.urlLoader(MainActivity.java:109)
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at com.example.mari.myandorid2.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:23)
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at com.example.mari.myandorid2.MainActivity$1.postExecute(MainActivity.java:69)
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at com.example.mari.myandorid2.AsyncFileDownload.doInBackground(AsyncFileDownload.java:78)
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at com.example.mari.myandorid2.AsyncFileDownload.doInBackground(AsyncFileDownload.java:19)
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:  Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.mari.myandroid.TestDinamicLoad" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:          ... 12 more
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:      Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.mari.myandroid.TestDinamicLoad
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:              ... 13 more
    12-26 23:20:34.817 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available


    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani: dexLoader------
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.mari.myandroid.TestDinamicLoad" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/com.example.mari.myandorid2/files/TestDinamicLoad.class"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at com.example.mari.myandorid2.MainActivity.dexLoader(MainActivity.java:91)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at com.example.mari.myandorid2.MainActivity.access$300(MainActivity.java:23)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at com.example.mari.myandorid2.MainActivity$1.postExecute(MainActivity.java:70)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at com.example.mari.myandorid2.AsyncFileDownload.doInBackground(AsyncFileDownload.java:78)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at com.example.mari.myandorid2.AsyncFileDownload.doInBackground(AsyncFileDownload.java:19)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:  Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Expected valid zip or dex file: '/data/data/com.example.mari.myandorid2/files/TestDinamicLoad.class'
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:295)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:111)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadDex(DexFile.java:151)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:265)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:231)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:109)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at dalvik.system.DexClassLoader.<init>(DexClassLoader.java:57)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at com.example.mari.myandorid2.MainActivity.dexLoader(MainActivity.java:90)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:          ... 10 more
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:  Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.mari.myandroid.TestDinamicLoad" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mari.myandorid2-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:          ... 12 more
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:      Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.mari.myandroid.TestDinamicLoad
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:              ... 13 more
    12-26 23:20:34.837 19078-19264/com.example.mari.myandorid2 V/murotani:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Refered: 
[ClassNotFoundException during Dynamic Class loading in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420225/classnotfoundexception-during-dynamic-class-loading-in-android)
http://tech.co/android-security-2014-07
http://larshamren.blogspot.jp/2012/02/android-dynamically-loading-classes.html

Comment: Dynamically load an Activity? I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: For point number 1, please post the complete stack trace of the exception, also telling if it's for pattern A or B. About point number 2, you can easily add all the XML files and resources you want, but do that before the building process is started because in the APK XML resources are in binary format. Point number 3, is not possible without a trick: when the application is installed, all the Activities declared in the manifest are "registered". So, if you load at runtime an Activity that was not present in the manifest at installation time, you'll get an exception.

Comment: see [dynamic load framework for android](https://github.com/singwhatiwanna/dynamic-load-apk/blob/master/README-en.md)

Comment: Maybe this help you https://github.com/lukeFalsina/Grab-n-Run